# Angular 2 navigation menu routing

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I need to develop single page application which should have the following "pages": 
1. Login page with very simple form
2. Home page with navigation menu on the left and in the remaining part of the screen the specific content of the chosen section should be displayed.

I do know the routing basics so I have created the following router:

```js
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";

import { LoginComponent } from "../login/login.component";
import { HomeComponent } from "../home/home.component";

export const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' }
]
```

It allows me to switch between the login page and the home page using button's `routerLink` attribute.

The first questions is how do I implement switching between the sections using the navigation menu on the home page? Imagine I have 'Clients' and 'Reports' sections (each section has its own functionality, buttons, labels, etc.) in the navigation menu. How can I implement routing to these modules?
Here is the draft code I have:

```html
<mat-sidenav-container fullscreen>
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" opened="true">
    <div fxLayout="column"> 
        <button mat-button>Clients</button>
        <button mat-button>Reports</button>
    </div>
 </mat-sidenav>

  <div>
    Some content specific for section here
  </div>

</mat-sidenav-container>
```

My second question is what will be the correct hierarchy for my project? Should the login and the home pages be the separate modules? And how should I organise (in terms of modules/components) the main content of home page which will be changing depending on the selected section?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) You can create links to the various routes by using the `routerLink` attribute.  For instance, you could design a navbar which looks like:

```
<nav>
  <a routerLink="/home"> Home </a>
  <a routerLink="/login"> Login </a>
</nav>
```

[more about this syntax is here.](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLink#how-to-use)

2) **For modules**: the primary benefit of creating multiple modules is that you can [lazy load](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/modules/lazy-loading-module.html) them- that is, load the module only after a certain route is activated.  Thus the standard is to create a separate module for each functional component of the website.  For instance- if I were to design an Angular 2 App which emulated Google Drive, I would have separate modules for user login, directory view, the document editor, the spreadsheet editor, the Presentation editor, etc- as different code is loaded depending on the route.

**For components**: I think there are two reasons to create separate components: 1) to reuse code across different views / components / inside a for loop and 2) to separate your code into better logical parts for data modelling. Generally, I make a separate component for each view (`/account`), and then create additional components any time a component would be reused.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Seems like my question was not really accurate. I've made some updates, can you please review them?

Comment: @NikitaMarinosyan Absolutely! I think you should read some about Lazy Loading (https://namitamalik.github.io/Lazy-Loading-with-Angular2-Routing/)- it handles how to load a different module based on each route, which it sounds like what you are looking for.

Comment: thanks mate!
P.S.: the link is broken, I think you will help a lot of newbies, if you remove the bracket from the end :D

Answer (score 0):

1) You can navigate via a routerLink in your template

```
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="nav-item" routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="scrollToTop()">
    login
  </div>
  <div class="nav-item" routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="scrollToTop()">
    home
  </div>
</nav>
```

2) I prefer to use a separate module (feature module) per feature, coupled with its own routing module. It keeps everything clean. For further reading you can visit the angular styleguide: https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#feature-modules

Comment: Thanks for the attention to my question, but you must have misunderstood my question, my bad. Imagine I have 'Clients' and 'Reports' sections (each section has its own functionality, buttons, labels, etc.) in the navigation menu. According to your answer, 'Clients' and 'Reports' should be the different modules. Now going back to my 1 question, how can I implement the the routing to these modules?

Comment: Within the lazy loading link above you have the answer to your question. FYI, you do not have to lazy load modules to achieve what you want.

Comment: Sure. Thank you!